# Why is theta limited to $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ while finding the hough transform

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, computer-vision

I was going through the source for [hough transform](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/d325ef60c2ae7404c664cfa301e0865c9ae15c96/skimage/transform/hough_transform.py#L220) in skimg library. I am not understanding why they have limited the value of $\theta$ from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Why can't they consider all $2\pi$ radians to detect the lines? For example, consider a line cutting through the second quadrant ((x1, y1) = (-3, 0) and (x2, y2) = (0, 3)). Here the $\theta$ > $\pi/2$. Why are all these lines being ignored?

Comment: Positive $90$ degrees followed by negative $90$ degrees sounds like a full $180$ degrees of motion, and for a line this is the full range of motion.  If you considered a full $2\pi$ radians that would be considering every possible line twice.  Note that $\theta\gt \frac {\pi}2\implies\theta-\pi\gt-\frac{\pi}2$.

Comment: ah thank you very much. This makes sense. Missed the double counting part.